# allocate a pointer with integers

Tags: c++

I have a problem

```
struct bin
{
    int *vector;
    bin *next;
};

bin *v = new bin;
```

and in a function I have:

```
 v->vector = new int[3];
 // etc.
```

The idea is that: if I put `v->vector[20] = 3;` it's working, and I don't know why because I expected to have a error. I think i don't understand very wheel what `v->vector = new int[1];` is doing .I thought it's allocated 3 int for the vector : `v->vector[1],v->vector[2],v->vector[3]`.can someone explain to me why `v->vector[20]=3;`doesn't give me an error? Thanks

Comment: This is C++, not C! Do not use unrelated tags.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I assume you run your app at high level OS (Windows, Linux)? 
Your process will be mapped certain amount of physical memory by default.

When you did your allocation for `vector[]` the system allocates memory from that mapped by default physical memory (performance optimization).

When you start going via vector[] then as long as you are within valid memory address your program will not crash.

If you try to read/write vector[33776] then most probably your program will crash (*most probably*, since the behavior when accessing non-allocated memory is undefined).

Answer (score 2):

It's not working. It's giving "undefined behavior" - you have written into memory that you shouldn't have.
C++ doesn't have array bounds checking, if you need it you'll have to do it yourself, perhaps by adding the size to the struct?

```
struct bin
{
    int *vector;
    int vectorSize;
    bin*next;
};
```

Also, C++ indexes arrays from 0, not 1, so the items you have can be accessed via: `v->vector[0]`, `v->vector[1]`, and `v->vector[2]`

Last but not least, calling it `vector` when there is already a very common c++ vector class may be a bit confusing. You could always look into the existing `stl::vector` class which may do what you need anyway.